# Оператор сравнения == в С++

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Как реализовать сравнение двух переменных, чтобы получить значение типа `bool`, говорящее, равны они или нет.
Что надо изменять? Написал вроде бы правильно, но нет никакой реакции   на `p2==p;`, нет даже вывода в консоль ни нуля, ни единички.

И как реализовать операторы `>`, `>=` и подобные?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class abstact
 {
public:
virtual void input () = 0;
virtual void output () = 0;
virtual void rachet () = 0;

};


class racheti:public abstact
{
private:
    float ksi;
    float speed;
    float alfa;
    float ro;
    float Relson;
    float nu;
    float f;
    float S;
    float test;
public:
    friend bool operator==(racheti &a, racheti &b);
      void input()
    {
        ro=1.29;
        speed=8;
        alfa=1e-3;
        nu=1.73e-5;
        cout << "S =";
        cin  >> S;
    }
    void output()
    {
        cout << "F = " << f << " Relson = " << Relson << " S = " << S << " KSI = "<< ksi << endl;
    }
    void rachet()
    {
        Relson=(speed*alfa*ro)/nu;

        if(Relson<=2)
        {
            ksi=24/Relson;
        }
        else if(Relson>2 && Relson<=500)
        {
            ksi=18.5/(pow(Relson,0.6));
        }
        else if(Relson>500){ksi = 0.44;}

        f=ksi*S*((ro*pow(speed,2))/2);

    }


};
int main()
{
    int a;
   abstact *p = new racheti; // * В покажчик р на базовий клас заноситься адреса, виділена під об'єкт похідного класу crug * /
    p ->input();
    p ->rachet();
    p ->output();
    cout << endl;
    abstact *p2 = new racheti;
    p2 ->input();
    p2 ->rachet();
    p2 ->output();

    p2==p;

    return 0;
}
bool operator==(racheti &a, racheti &b)
    {
        if(a==b)
          return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Первое: Вы сравниваете два указателя, а не сами объекты p2==p. Второе: ну так надо самому указывать что хотите вывести результат в консоль или куда там Вам надо.

Answer (score 7):

Что? Требуется сравнить `a` и `b`? Нет вопросов! Смотрим типы... ага! вот он, оператор сравнения `a` и `b`! Поехали...

```
bool operator==(racheti &a, racheti &b)
{
    if(a==b) return 1;
```

Что? Требуется сравнить `a` и `b`? Нет вопросов! Смотрим типы... ага! Вот он -

```
bool operator==(racheti &a, racheti &b)
{
    if(a==b) return 1;
```

Что? Требуется сравнить `a` и `b`? Нет вопросов! Смотрим типы... ага! Вот он - ...

Ну, вы поняли, что въехали в бесконечную рекурсию?...

А вот если встретится

```
    if(a.ksi   != b.ksi) return 0;
    if(a.speed != b.speed) return 0;
    ...
```

то будет примерно так - ага, тут нас просят сравнить два `float`. Нет вопросов - это встроенный оператор сравнения, вызываем его.

Comment: как быть в  такой ситуации?

Comment: Сравнивайте не `a==b`, а некие внутренние поля, по которым они будут равны. Например `a.value == b.value`, при условии, что `value` имеет тип, для которого определен оператор ==

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: Не пойму все равно, не могли бы вы дать пожалуйста код, который можно вставить. Играюсь уже долго  - безрезультатно

Comment: Чтоб написать - нужно понимать, что такое у вас равенство. Дайте определение, какие объекты считать равными? Только учтите, что сравнивать на равенство два числа с плавающей точкой можно только с определенной точностью! просто писать `==` - не стоит...

Comment: А какой будет лучше float в данном случае или double?

Comment: Если нет каких-то особых ограничений - от препода или там на объем памяти - то `double` лучше.

Comment: неплохо бы ещё `const` добавить в сигнатурах